# How to remove additional space in served plain text file content with PHP Development Server?

Tags: php, html, webserver, removing-whitespace

I have a plain text file named `index.html` that contains a single word with 5 characters <s>with no EOL character</s> and with no HTML tags.

Contents of `index.html`:

```
Hamid
```

I want to serve it on web with *PHP Development Server*. So I opened a Terminal in the folder containing `index.html` file and ran:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

It becomes accessible via `http://localhost:8000/index.html` and the content of the `index.html` file `Hamid` is shown in the Safari browser.

[image: Safari Web Inspector]

But in the Web Inspector there is an additional space after the word `Hamid` and before `</body>` tag:

```
<body>Hamid </body>
```

I tried change the content of `index.html` to what I want to be represented:

```
<html><head></head><body>Hamid</body></html>
```

But the result is the same. It will be changed to:

```
<html><head></head><body>Hamid </body></html>
```

I tried to test the served page with this command in Terminal:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/index.html | wc
```

But the result shows that the output has `6` characters instead of `5` characters:

```
1       1       6
```

How can I prevent this additional space to be reproduced?

**EDIT**: I made the `index.html` file with this command:

```
echo "Hamid" > index.html
```

In addition, I **do not want** to use any PHP code or modification tricks to original file served by the web server. Just to present the original file itself.

**UPDTE**: Thanks to @Jeff and @atul-jindal, I tested the size of `index.html` that is created with `echo` command and found extra `0A` at the end of file. This is the output of `xxd index.html`:

```
00000000: 4861 6d69 640a                           Hamid.
```

Instead of `echo "Hamid" > index.html` I should use `echo -n "Hamid" > index.html`.

But it is not solved yet. As I mentioned above, I used this command to create `index.html`:

```
echo "<html><head></head><body>Hamid</body></html>" > index.html
```

After that, contents of `index.html` with an extra `0A` is:

```
00000000: 3c68 746d 6c3e 3c68 6561 643e 3c2f 6865  <html><head></he
00000010: 6164 3e3c 626f 6479 3e48 616d 6964 3c2f  ad><body>Hamid</
00000020: 626f 6479 3e3c 2f68 746d 6c3e 0a         body></html>.
```

Now, with Safari there is extra space after `Hamid` exactly like the image above; with `curl` this extra space is after `</html>` closing tag like the original file. Why this is happened in the browser?

Comment: maybe your editor adds the additional EOL?

Comment: @jeff I added the command to create the file

Answer (score 1):

When you create file, it automatically adds extra space character at EOL. you can use trim function to remove white space. Additionally, when you output as HTTP request, in browser it will add up HTML tags to request as it is HTML document.

Comment: I added the command to create the file in my question. adding the html tags is not the problem because it is just browser-related. with using `curl` it has no tags. and I do not want to use code to `edit` the file. I want to use the web server to serve the original file without modifications.